# Custom format wrong output

Tags: excel

I have 12 and 13 digits number in column. I using custom format `### ### ### ### #` but I get numbers formatted incorrectly:

```
693 751 571 314 6 
69 510 843 314 1
```

I need:

```
693 751 571 314 6 
695 108 433 141
```

How to write right custom format for that?

Comment: Excel will always fill the `#` from right to left. Maybe you can hide the decimal separator to not display and try to make the trailing single digit to be a decimal part...

Comment: Problem solved with below answer? Still need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
[>999999999999]### ### ### ### #;[<=999999999999]### ### ### ###
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely short-sighted but it will accommodate your two sample numbers.

Use a custom number format mask of `[>999999999999]000 000 000 000 0;000 000 000 000`.

You can set two numerical comparisons with a custom number format and have a third as the default.

[image: CNF_000]

The cells in the right-hand column are formatted with `[>999999999999]000 000 000 000 0;[>99999999999]000 000 000 000;000 000 000 00`.